# Is there a validation object contains the form value when failed validation in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation

I am a new Laravel user. When creating a form like create/edit product. After validating the form, when it's fail because of some missing fields and redirect back.

At the point, Laravel auto fill the sumitted value of fields. How can I get value of the fields was submitted at last step like "name" "sku".... ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the old() method to fetch the previous submitted record in laravel form try like this

```
    <input id="company_name" name="company_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" value="{{old('company_name')}}">

@if ($errors->has('company_name'))
 <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('company_name') }}</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If I underrating correctly you need function `old()`, use like this: `{{ old('name') }}`.
Example, to show previous value of the input:
`<input type=“text” name=“name” value=“{{ old('name') }}”>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a input for name, you can get the old value in your form like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="nome">Name: </label>
   <input name="nome" id="name" class="form-control" value="{{old('name')}}">
</div>
```